# Tensorflow model not training

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

I am training my model using tensorflow-gpu.(I am using NVIDIA somewhere in the 1000 series)
When I hit run and the model start training, the val_accuracy stays in 0.5 and does not change. However, when I keep on trying without change of any codes, it trains the model occasinally, anyone experienced the same problem, or know why this is happening?

```
Epoch 13/72
24012/24012 [==============================] - 4s 172us/sample - loss: 7.6895 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.6685 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 14/72
24012/24012 [==============================] - 4s 172us/sample - loss: 7.6895 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.6685 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 15/72
24012/24012 [==============================] - 4s 169us/sample - loss: 7.6895 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.6685 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 16/72
24012/24012 [==============================] - 4s 169us/sample - loss: 7.6895 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 7.6685 - val_acc: 0.5000
```

Comment: It will let others provide you with more informed help if you include more information. For example, share some code and tell us what did you try and what has failed.

Comment: @ShahanM Hello, thanks for letting me know I forgot to add my output result.

Comment: post your training ocde at least a sample which effectively reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that

1. You did not normalize your input data (most likely the cause)
2. You used easily-saturated activation functions like `sigmoid`

What may happen then is that your model's initial guess is way off and put the activation functions to their saturated region where little to no learning happens (because of near zero gradient).

The model may be able to learn sometimes when you repeatedly retrain it because its weights are randomly initialized every time, which may sometimes put the initial guess at reasonable values.

Comment: I didn't know that I had to normalize my input data. But I did normalize it and the problem is solved! Thank you!